# How to update the Data Catalog tag values through airflow CloudDataCatalog operators

Tags: airflow, google-data-catalog, google-dataplex

I would like to update Data Catalog tags through airflow CloudDataCatalog operators and schedule the DAG to update the tag values daily. This is to capture the ETL status on a BigQuery table and feed that status  to Data Catalog tag. Could you please help me on what approach I should take?

I explored and found airflow offers Data Catalog related operators but I could find any actual use to alter the tag values in any platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used these operators before but sounds like the [CloudDataCatalogUpdateTagOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/google/modules/clouddatacatalogupdatetagoperator) should be exactly what you need.

I found this example code in the [provider docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/datacatalog.html#updating-a-tag):

```py
update_tag = CloudDataCatalogUpdateTagOperator(
    task_id="update_tag",
    tag={"fields": {FIELD_NAME_1: TagField(string_value="new-value-string")}},
    update_mask={"paths": ["fields"]},
    location=LOCATION,
    entry_group=ENTRY_GROUP_ID,
    entry=ENTRY_ID,
    tag_id=tag_id,
    gcp_conn_id=YOUR GCP AIRFLOW CONNECTION # added this line in case you don't use the default conn id string
)
```